# BIRT 4.3.2 on Tomcat 7.0.53 on windows 8.1 64 bit gives error 'Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc. '

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jdbc, birt

I have been working on creating report using BIRT with MySql. While I am able to run the report successfully using BIRT viewer, when I try to integrate with tomcat, it gives the below **error**

> org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: An exception
>   occurred during processing. Please see the following message for
>   details: Cannot open the connection for the driver:
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: Failed to get
>   connection. SQL error #1:Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO) ; java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

the error message indicates that you do not have permissions to loging to MySQL database using root without any password. As far as I remember, default password for root is 'sa' in MySQL. Please check whether you need any password for your database.